# C# Webservice, unable to automatically step into the server. .. remote debugger does not support this edition of windows

Tags: c#, webserver

This is being a pain. I had a working logging system using web services but connecting to my local. Now i have launched them onto my web server i have come across a dilemma.

When i create an account the program goes through the web service and saves the information on the web server.

But now when i go to log in. I get this error:

> "Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the
>   server machine "EXAMPLE.COM" failed. The Visual Studio Remote Debugger
>   does not support this edition of windows.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remote debug the web services which are running on remote server you have to install the Remote Debugger on that server where they are depoyed. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) you can find how to do that

After this you can attach the remote process as you normally would do for a local one.